# MongoDB change streams guaranteed delivery?

Tags: mongodb, rethinkdb

I was about to choose RethinkDB for a chat application I'm building because of it's [changefeeds](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/ruby/) functionality, but then I found out that MongoDB has something which looks similar, called [Change streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/). What are the most notable difference between these two?

In particular, I saw on the RethinkDB documentation that:

> Since changefeeds are unidirectional with no acknowledgement returned from clients, they cannot guarantee delivery. If you need real-time updating with delivery guarantees, consider using a model that distributes to the clients through a message broker such as RabbitMQ.

I was wondering whether MongoDB change streams is the same? Am I guaranteed to receive an update every time the data changes, or not?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB change streams are pulled by the client, not pushed by the server.

The client receives a resume token with each batch of updates, and passes that token back when requesting more from the server.

This is not quite a guarantee though.  Change streams depend on the replica set oplog, so if the client waits too long before requesting more data, the event indicated by the resume token may have been purged from the oplog, and the client will receive an error indicating that updates were probably missed.